# Over-ride behavior of another plug-in

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jstree

I have a plug-in that does some hover and select effects on a tree 'li' however I want this function to be over-ridden with the behavior of a twitter bootstrap function.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('a').popover({
    animation: 'true',
    placement: 'right',
    trigger: 'hover'}
  );
  });
```

If I paste that snippet into firebug console it works, but if I have this function in the code it doesn't. The other plug-in seems to take precedence for some reason. I have my bootstrap function as the last function called, not sure why it is not able to over-ride.

I also have the tree.js coming in before I have the popover.js Shouldn't the popover.js over-ride the tree.js?

Comment: could be a conflict? anyway you should paste all your code here or jsfiddle.net or pastebin.com

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").on("hover", function(){
 $('a').popover({
    animation: 'true',
    placement: 'right',
    trigger: 'hover'}
 )
});
```